# How to paste from register within a keybinding expression?

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

I want to open the file of the path within my clipboard in the current buffer using a key binding.

```
<CMD>e <C-r>+<CR>
```

is the thing I want to do. Doing this manually works, but doing this via keybinding will just open an empty buffer. How can I bind `<C-r>+` properly?

Answer (score 2):

A different way:

```
<Cmd>execute 'edit' @+
```

But pay attention to filenames with spaces and special characters.

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to handle spaces though?

Comment: @MartinBraun perhaps the function fnameescape or shellescape or similar?

Answer (score 1):

"cmd" enters command (almost like "script") mode. While control-r-plus belongs to command-line (interactive, typing) mode. So they don't work together. Use "colon" instead of that funny "cmd", for example. Also, always pay attention to the mode Vim is currently in. That may have unexpected consequences.